# 行ごとに背景色を変えるさえ、input要素も背景色をかえるには？

Tags: css, html5

```css
 .trColor tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #edf7e8; }
 .trColor tr:nth-child(odd){  background-color: #ffffd0; }
```

```html
    <html>
    <table class="trColor">
    <tr>
    　　<td>aaa</td>
       <td><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>aaa</td>
       <td><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>aaa</td>
       <td><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </html>

<!-- end sni
```

aaa　は行ごとに色が変わっていると思うのですが、
inputの背景色も行ごとに色を変えるにはどうしたらいいのでしょうか？
innerTextではだめで、必ずinputです。
できるだけ、cssだけで実現させたいのですが、難しくて分かりません。

ご教授よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inputにも指定を当てる方法ではダメなのでしょうか？

```css
.trColor tr:nth-child(even),
.trColor tr:nth-child(even) input {
   background-color: #edf7e8;
}

.trColor tr:nth-child(odd),
.trColor tr:nth-child(odd) input {
   background-color: #ffffd0;
}
```

```html
<html>
<table class="trColor">
    <tr>
        <td>aaa</td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>aaa</td>
       <td><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>aaa</td>
       <td><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</html>
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。もし、input要素が横に３つならんでて任意のinputだけ背景色変更する方法ってありますか？

Comment: 色を変えたいinputに任意のclassをつけて、input要素ではなくclassに対して背景色の指定をすればよいかと。